# Xamp issue on deploying site

Tags: php, web-services, web, xampp

I got a php website from my friend  i need to run this on my pc . when i run this the site using xamp it  is not running completely the pictures which are used in it are broken is there any solution to it ?

Comment: Change the paths to the images; add the images to your local system... Hard to say with no code..

Answer (score 0):

The links are definitely broken just like @chris85 said.

Check all the href attributes and links and make sure your giving them the right path to your images or what not. If your running over Windows it should be C:/Xampp/htdocs/ProjectName/...

You can use a built in function being dirname(**FILE**)  to get to the root of your project.